# How to implement "Uses Per Customer" in Catalog Rules?

Tags: magento2, catalog, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

How can I implement "Uses Per Customer" functionality (Same Like Cart Price Rules) in Catalog Rules?

Say for example. If I enter 3 in Uses Per Customers. Catalog Price rule has to apply only 3 times for that customers. Next time onwards customers don't get the catalog discount.

How can I achieve this?

Please share your thoughts and ideas.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You will need to create a custom module using custom table with columns Rule_id, Customer_id,Times_Used.

Comment: Check this file for rule validation: Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule